# Accessing counter from two threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a counter that is being incremented from one thread. In the main thread, I basically print it out by calling data member of a class. In the below code, nothing is being printed out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mut;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const int& m) : m_delay(m), m_count(0)
    {}

    void update()
    {
        std::cout << "count: " << this->m_count << std::endl;
    }

     void operator()()  
     {
        while (true){
            mut.lock();
            m_count++;
            mut.unlock();

            Sleep(m_delay);
        }
     } 

private:
    int m_delay;
    int m_count;
};

Foo *obj = new Foo(200);

int main() 
{
    std::thread *t = new std::thread(*obj);
    t->join();

    while(true)
    {
        obj->update();

        Sleep(10);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your question "why is nothing being printed out?" or is this post more of a statement? : )

Comment: Dont need to user a lock in this code....

Comment: @CroCo When do you expect `t->join()` to return?

Comment: @Biffen, I've moved `join()` after `while` but the count is not updated.

Comment: If you've changed the code then please update the question. As written it's never going to print anything because the `main` thread blocks at the join. Why are you creating your objects with `new`? Why are you [not using a scoped lock](http://kayari.org/cxx/antipatterns.html#locking-mutex)?

Comment: @JonathanWakely, I've accepted your answer and removed my answer to remove any confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the original code is that this copies the `Foo` object:

```
std::thread *t = new std::thread(*obj);
```

That means that the increments happen to the copy, and so the value in the original `Foo` never changes, and so when `main` prints it out (if you move the misplaced `join()`) the value is always the same.

A solution is to use a reference not a copy:

```
std::thread *t = new std::thread(std::ref(*obj));
```

You also need to protect the read of the variable by the mutex (or use `std::atomic<int>` for the counter) to avoid undefined behaviour caused by concurrently reading and writing a non-atomic variable.

You should also stop using `mut.lock()` and `mut.unlock()` directly, [use a scoped lock](http://kayari.org/cxx/antipatterns.html#locking-mutex) instead.

There's also no need to create things on the heap unnecessarily, overusing `new` is a bad habit of people who learnt Java and C# first.

You can also make the code portable by replacing the Windows-specific `Sleep` call with standard C++.

A correct version would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mut;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(std::chrono::milliseconds m) : m_delay(m), m_count(0)
    {}

    void update()
    {
        int count = 0;
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
            count = m_count;
        }
        std::cout << "count: " << count << std::endl;
    }

     void operator()()  
     {
        while (true)
        {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
                m_count++;
            }

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(m_delay);
        }
     } 

private:
    std::chrono::milliseconds m_delay;
    int m_count;
};

Foo obj(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));

int main() 
{
    std::thread t(std::ref(obj));
    while(true)
    {
        obj.update();

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, use an atomic variable so you don't need the mutex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(std::chrono::milliseconds m) : m_delay(m), m_count(0)
    {}

    void update()
    {
        std::cout << "count: " << m_count << std::endl;
    }

     void operator()()  
     {
        while (true)
        {
            m_count++;

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(m_delay);
        }
     } 

private:
    std::chrono::milliseconds m_delay;
    std::atomic<int> m_count;
};

Foo obj(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));

int main() 
{
    std::thread t(std::ref(obj));
    while(true)
    {
        obj.update();

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why you added `{ }` inside the while loop?

Comment: To release the mutex lock before sleeping. The constructor of the `lock_guard` acquires the lock, and the destructor releases it. Otherwise the lock will be held while sleeping and the other thread will not be able to lock it to read the value. I've added another version that uses an atomic variable, so the mutex isn't needed.